# Where do Saints go after we return with Jesus (Pentecostal perspective)

Tags: exegesis, eschatology, revelation, pentecostalism, new-earth

I was wondering where the glorified Saints go to live after we return with Jesus as described in Revelation 19:11–16:

> And I saw Heaven opened, and behold a white horse; and he that sat upon him was called faithful and True, and in righteousness he doth judge and make war.
>    His eyes were as a flame of fire, and on his head were many crowns; and he had a name written, that no man knew, but he himself.
>    And he was clothed with vesture dipped in blood: and his name is called The Word of God.
>    And the armies which were Heaven followed him upon white horses, clothed in fine linen, white and clean. And out of his mouth goeth a sharp sword, that with it he should smite the nations: and he shall rule them with a rod of iron: and he treadeth the wineprsee of the fierceness and wrath of Almighty God.
>   And he hath on his vesture and on his thigh a name written, King of Kings and Lord of Lords.

Do we stay in Israel or do we return to our homes?

I am interested in a Pentecostal perspective.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a distinctive Pentecostal perspective on this that differs from any other literal, futurist interpretation. I believe that all such persons become part of Christ's worldwide government:

> And he who overcomes, and keeps My works until the end, to him I will give power over the nations—

```
 ‘​He shall rule them with a rod of iron;
 They shall be dashed to pieces like the potter’s vessels’—
```

> as I also have received from My Father; and I will give him the morning star. (Rev. 2:26-28)

They have authority over all the various places on Earth, while they may certainly be based in Israel, as Paul says that after the rapture and resurrection, "**And thus we shall always be with the Lord**" (1 Thess. 4:17).